# "Illeism" em português

Tags: tradução-inglês

Estava a ler sobre o termo inglês *[Illeism](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illeism)*,

> excessive use of the pronoun he especially in reference to oneself.

Uma vez que procurava entender o que sites em português tinham a dizer sobre o termo, recorri ao DeepL e Google Translate para tradução.

- DeepL -> Illeísmo
- Google Translate -> Illeism

Procurando no Priberam, por exemplo, não encontro nada sobre a mesma.

Será que o mesmo existe / faz sentido em português? Se sim, qual a palavra correta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### «Ileísmo»

Vendo o inglês «*illeism*», a palavra «ileísmo» ou «eleísmo», se pensarmos na etimologia do termo, parecem possíveis traduções. Porém, nenhum dos dicionário que vi (Michaelis, Aulete, Dicio, Priberam e Houaiss) apresentou «eleísmo» ou «ileísmo», salvo o Dicio, que apresentou para «ileísmo»: **Grm Uso busivo e desnecess&cute;rio do pronome de 3. pesso.**, creio eu que equivalente a **Geralmente uso abusivo e desnecessário do pronome da 3ª pessoa**.

Pela má formatação do Dicio descrevendo a palavra e falta de imparcialidade, vou desconsiderar sua acepção de «ileísmo».

### Que termo usar?

Ao meu ver, há duas opções: optar por uma palavra já dicionarizada ou por um neologismo, uma palavra nova. Uma palavra dicionarizada seria uma opção mais segura.

#### Palavra Dicionarizada

Quando alguém está **falando de si na terceira pessoa** (ex.: «Calma, Carlos. Vamos terminar o dia sem fumar outro cigarro»), a pessoa está **se referenciando a si na terceira pessoa**, ou seja, **se autorreferenciando na terceira pessoa**. Como não chamamos “eu amo” de autorreferência, mesmo sendo, seria razoável usar apenas **autorreferência** em vez de **autorreferência na terceira pessoa**.

Outro modo seria usar «falar» ou «(autor)referenciar» como substantivo; ex.: «o falar de si é amiúde visto como infantilidade» e «autorreferenciar-se na tomada de decisão é estudado por cientistas». Existem provavelmente centenas de jeitos para expressar o ato de falar de si na terceira pessoa, mas *aparentemente* não há uma única palavra com esse significado.

#### Neologismo

Um neologismo é uma palavra nova que pode ser importada, como «*feedback*» e «*campus*», ou criada dentro da própria língua, como «chinelada» ou «gordamente». Assim poderíamos importar «ileísmo» do inglês «*illeism*».

Se não quisermos importar do inglês, temos algumas opções:

- Por analogia com o inglês, juntar latim {ille} com português {-ismo} para formar {ileísmo}, com um l porque no português não se escreve dois ll;
- Seguindo apenas o português, juntar latim {ille} com português {-ismo} para formar {ilísmo}, porque o {-e} em «*ille*» é átono, ou {ileísmo} se quisermos preservar mais o {ille};
- Como latim {ille} significa «ele» (e *ille* > *ele*), juntar {ele} com {-ismo}, que nos dá «elísmo» ou «eleísmo» se quisermos preservar mais o {ele}.

Interessante que em matéria do [Nexo](https://www.nexojornal.com.br/externo/2019/09/07/Por-que-falar-de-voc%C3%AA-na-3a-pessoa-te-torna-mais-s%C3%A1bio) e [Epoca.Globo](https://epoca.globo.com/sociedade/por-que-falar-na-terceira-pessoa-nos-faz-mais-inteligentes-23976986), usaram «ileísmo».

---

Nota: não estou excluindo outras formas, apenas apresentando algumas opções.